# Github actions lftp upload fails

Tags: github-actions, lftp

I'm attempting to upload two files to a vsftp server using lftp within a github action. One is a txt file of +-70 bytes. The other is a dll of +-20mb. The txt file succeeds to upload but the dll fails on a `426 Failure reading network stream.` error. When doing these operations by hand (in powershell on the build node itself) the upload succeeds, but when running in Github actions it fails.

The (simplified) pipeline code:

```yaml
#stuff for the trigger
jobs:
  Build-release:
    runs-on: [self-hosted, clr] #this is a windows server 2019 with lftp installed
    steps:
      #some steps for compiling and testing
      - name: Upload artifacts
        run: |
          lftp -d -c "set ssl:verify-certificate false; open -u ${{ vars.FTP_USER }},${{ secrets.FTP_PASS }} ${{ vars.FTP_URL }}; put -O plugins/ Plates-components.txt"
          lftp -d -c "set net:socket-maxseg 500; set ssl:verify-certificate false; open -u ${{ vars.FTP_USER }},${{ secrets.FTP_PASS }} ${{ vars.FTP_URL }}; put -O plugins/ Plates-components.dll"
        working-directory: ${{ github.workspace }}\src\Plates-components\bin\Release\netstandard2.0
```

a sample of the log from a failing build

```
Run lftp -d -c "set net:socket-maxseg 500; set ssl:verify-certificate false; open -u mc,*** ftps://hiddenurl:21; put -O plugins/ Plates-components.dll"
---- Resolving host address...
---- IPv6 is not supported or configured
---- 1 address found: 10.100.10.91
---- Connecting to hiddenurl (10.100.10.91) port 21
[hidden certificate]
Certificate verification: subjectAltName: ‘hiddenurl’ matched
<--- 220 MC plugins
---> FEAT
<--- 211-Features:
<---  AUTH SSL
<---  EPRT
<---  EPSV
<---  MDTM
<---  PASV
<---  PBSZ
<---  PROT
<---  REST STREAM
<---  SIZE
<---  TVFS
<--- 211 End
---> USER mc
<--- 331 Please specify the password.
---> PASS ***
<--- 230 Login successful.
---> PWD
<--- 257 "/" is the current directory
---> PBSZ 0
<--- 200 PBSZ set to 0.
---> PROT P
<--- 200 PROT now Private.
---> TYPE I
<--- 200 Switching to Binary mode.
---> PASV
<--- 227 Entering Passive Mode (10,100,10,91,82,13).
---- Connecting data socket to (10.100.10.91) port 21005
---- Data connection established
---> STOR plugins/Plates-components.dll
<--- 150 Ok to send data.
Certificate verification: subjectAltName: ‘hiddenurl’ matched
---- Closing data socket
<--- 426 Failure reading network stream.
---> QUIT
<--- 221 Goodbye.
---- Closing control socket
```

the client will just continue to loop this until a timeout or manual cancellation of the build

Things I tried to debug already:

- Use Filezilla on my laptop to test if the vsftp server is working and I can upload large (1gb+) files: yes
- Use lftp on my laptop to test if I can upload the same large file with the specific client: yes
- Run the upload commands on the buildserver by hand to see if it works then: Yes I can upload the exact dll that is failing in the action.
- Set `net:socket-maxseg` to some low number: did not help
- Set `strict_ssl_read_eof=NO` on the vsftpd server: did not help

I don't know where the difference can be. It works when doing it manually, it fails when running as an action. Any suggestions would be appreciated